# gSpice: 'model is not a mosfet' error message

Tags: spice, eda

I'm trying to simulate a circuit. So:

1. I run netlist on the `.sch` file. It completed successfully.
2. I've opened the `.net` file with gSpiceUI and tried to simulate, but an error was given:

> M1: model  is not a mosfet

The netlist file:

```
**************************************************************
*  Electronic circuit simulation file generated by gSpiceUI  *
*             Version 0.9.98 Alpha (14/10/2009)              *
**************************************************************

* Component Definitions
C1 1 2 100nF
CLoad 0 5 100uF
DOff 0 1 1N4007
DOn 1 3 1N4007
L1 3 2 22uH
M1 2 4 5 DMP2004WK
RLoad 0 5 1M
V1 5 3 DC 5V
* Signal source (V2 4 3 pulse 0 5 10n 10n 100n 1u 2u)
V2 4 3 GENERATOR(1)

* Model Definitions
.MODEL 1N4007 D(IS=76.9p RS=42.0m BV=1.00k IBV=5.00u CJO=26.5p  M=0.333 N=1.45 TT=4.32u)
.MODEL DMP2004WK PMOS( LEVEL=1 VTO=-1.00 KP=0.200  GAMMA=1.24
+ PHI=.75  LAMBDA=208u RD=0.126 RS=0.126
+ IS=200f  PB=0.800 MJ=0.460 CBD=40.6p 
+ CBS=48.7p  CGSO=240n CGDO=200n CGBO=1.31u  )

* GNU-Cap Simulation Commands
.OPTIONS NOPAGE
.PRINT TR V(RLoad)
.GENERATOR AMP=5.00 OFFSET=0.00 FREQ=1.00K PHASE=0.00 INIT=0.00 MIN=0.00 MAX=5.00 DELAY=0.00 RISE=0.00 WIDTH=5.00u FALL=0.00 PERIOD=1.00m
.TR 0.00m 10.00 50.00u TE 27.00 BASIC

.END
```

Do you know why this error appears how to make this working?

If any additional information is required plz ask, cuz I'm not sure if there's additional info I need to supply.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for gSpice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know gSpice specifically, but in ngSpice (a SPICE3-based free SPICE), the syntax for a MOSFET card is

> MXXXXXXX nd ng ns nb mname ...

Notice, four terminals must be specified: drain, gate, source, and body.

In your deck you specified only three connections, and the simulator probably thought `DMP2004WK` was the name of a new node where the body is connected.

Typically the body of a PMOS should be connected to the source or to a positive voltage rail.

Comment: Hey you're right! It worked. I've tried it earlier but it didn't help that time, don't know why...